# Change camera orientation when ipad rotates

Tags: objective-c, ipad, camera

Iam using the following code for capturing the image from Ipad:

```
if ( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = imagePickerDelegate;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera | UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    UIPopoverController                  *popover;
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
    [popover setContentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

My Problem is that when i rotate the ipad from portrait to landscape, camera still showing me the portrait image. But when I use full screen for imagepicker it works fine. An idea how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) the `UIImagePickerController` does not support horizontal mode.

> **Important** The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode
>   only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not
>   be modified, with one exception. In iOS 3.1 and later, you can assign
>   a custom view to the `cameraOverlayView` property and use that view to
>   present additional information or manage the interactions between the
>   camera interface and your code.

Comment: But camera rotates when I use full screen and dont use popover controller what about that.